# Is it possible to send signal to capture remotely to 40 cameras over wifi simulatenously?

Tags: sony-camera-api

I want to develop a software which may be in any programming language. The program will send signal at the same time (ignoring delays caused by hardware) to 40 cameras to take picture of an scene from different angles.

Comment: Ooh, that's a cool project. Best of luck with it! Have you tried it, though?

Comment: wow! that will revolutionize the industry, when you can completely ignore hardware delays and get the response instantly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers,

I have succesfully achieved what I have explained in my question. This is possible using Canon Cameras and a Canon Camera Hack Development Kit aka [chdk](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) and its extension chdkptp. You can see link : [Multiple Cameras](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/Multiple_Cameras_using_CHDK)

*I have searched the site but could not find any question about this that's why I wanted to share my knowledge for future askers.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about using our remote camera API it will be difficult as you will only be able to connect to one camera over Wifi at a time.